# Show loader gif until backend is finished

Tags: javascript, html, jsf

I am looking for solutions to display "loader gif" until action is done on backend.

I have a xhtml page which use JSF. On page is button like this.

```
<h:commandButton class="buttonNormal background"
                 id="button"
                 action="#{uploadTitleSSB.insertTitle()}"
                 value="#{lang['uploadTitle.button.upload']}"/>
```

I want to display "loader gif" until action `#{uploadTitleSSB.insertTitle()}` which is called on button click is done.
This action can take max 5 min. And I dont know which page will be shown after action is done. From method insertTitle() is returned string with new page.

Example of insertTitle() method:

```
public String insertTitle()
{       
    if(....)
    {
        //do work
        return "somePage1";
    }
    else if(....)
    {
        //do work
        return "somePage2";
    }
    return null;
}
```

There is one more thing, that button is inside a form in which are some validators. These validators call methods on backend and can throw error messages.

Comment: r u using jquery ? any  javascript plugin ?

Comment: No, I am not. But I prefer javascript if it is important for answer...

Comment: What user can do when the task is being processed? He can just watch loading gif for 5 minutes until action completes or is it done asynchronously? Because method does a redirect/forward I assume user can just watch gif without switching pages. In this case you can just do `onclick=showGif();` which shows gif and when action completes it will redirect user and gif automatically disappears.

Comment: Geinmachi.

Its done synchronously from some reasons... So yes, he can just look on gif. But that method can return null. What to do then, how to hide that gif, when my method return null?
Like I see, I forgot say one more thing. That button is for form in which is a validator on inputFile, validator call method on backend. This validator can throw error message when some problems with inputFile in form ocurs.
I will add this in few min to question.